# Modifying content of NamedTemporaryFile (Python 3)

Tags: python, json, file-io, temporary-files

I'm unable to modify the content of a NamedTemporaryFile after having created it initially.

As per my example below, I create a NamedTemporaryFile from the content of a URL (JSON data).

Then, what I aim to do is re-access that file, modify some of the content of the JSON in the file, and save it. The code below is my attempt to do so.

```
import json
import requests

from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile


def create_temp_file_from_url(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    temp_file = NamedTemporaryFile(mode='w+t', delete=False)
    temp_file.write(response.text)
    temp_file.close()
    return temp_file.name


def add_content_to_json_file(json_filepath):
    file = open(json_filepath)
    content = json.loads(file.read())

    # Add a custom_key : custom_value pair in each dict item
    for repo in content:
        if isinstance(repo, dict):
            repo['custom_key'] = 'custom_value'

    # Close file back ... if needed?
    file.close()

    # Write my changes to content back into the file
    f = open(json_filepath, 'w')   # Contents of the file disappears...?
    json.dumps(content, f, indent=4)  # Issue: Nothing is written to f
    f.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sample_url = 'https://api.github.com/users/mralexgray/repos'

    tempf = create_temp_file_from_url(sample_url)

    # Add extra content to Temporary file
    add_content_to_json_file(tempf)

    try:
        updated_file = json.loads(tempf)
    except Exception as e:
        raise e
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1: This line:

```
json.dumps(content, f, indent=4)  # Issue: Nothing is written to f
```

doesn't dump `content` to `f`. It makes a string from `content`, with `skipkeys` value `f`, and then does nothing with it.

You probably wanted `json.dump`, with no `s`..

2: This line

```
    updated_file = json.loads(tempf)
```

tries to load a JSON object from the temp filename, which isn't going to work.  You'll have to either read the file in as a string and then use `loads`, or re-open the file and use `json.load`.

Comment: Thank you! That resolved my issue.

Small IO question:
If I call `content = json.loads(open(json_filepath).read())`, does the file need to be closed afterwards before I can write to it again?